# Fastest way to add matrices of different shapes in Python/Numba

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vectorization, numba

I want to "add" two matrices, a matrix `a` with shape (`K,T`) and a matrix `b` of shape `(K,N)`, to result in a matrix of shape `(K,T,N`)

The following works ok:

```py
import numpy as np 
from numba import njit

@njit
def add_matrices(a, b):
    K, T, N = a.shape[0], a.shape[1], b.shape[1]
    result_matrix = np.empty((K, T, N))
    
    for k in range(K):
        for t in range(T):
            for n in range(N):
                result_matrix[k, t, n] = a[k, t] + b[k, n]
    
    return result_matrix


K = 10
T = 11
N = 12
a = np.ones((K,T))
b = np.ones((K,N))

result = add_matrices(a, b)
```

Is there a faster (vectorized?) way to do it that doesn't require the for loops, which I think is slowing down the function, especially for larger values of `K, T,N`?

Comment: Make two 3D matrices (both with dimension K, T, N); Repeat `a` N times for the first matrix, repeat `b` T times for the second matrix. Then add the two 3D matrices together.

Comment: @MatBailie no need to repeat. Just adding an extra axis in the correct position (like Frank's answer shows) is good enough. Numpy's [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) feature is really useful

Comment: You're already using `numba .njit` to precompile your code. Numpy isn't likely to speed it up much more

Comment: Do you really need to allocate result_matrix on every call of the function? Reusing this matrix is the most obvious way to further gain performance. The for loops are no problem when using Numba. Actually it is often beneficial to rewrite vectorized numpy code to simple loops to gain performance, but on this very simple problem this may not have an influence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

```
a[:,:,None] + b[:,None,:]
```

This makes `a` appear to have size [K, T, 1], and `b` to have size `[K, 1, N]`.  Numpy knows how to add these two together.

Comment: This is great. I think to make jit compatible we have to use `reshape`

Answer (score 1):

For me, the accepted answer is slower than the original code, even if combined with numba.njit (combining with nit actually makes it slower for large `K, T, N`). If `K, T, N` are large then you can speed up your original code with [numba.prange](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/parallel.html#explicit-parallel-loops):

```py
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def add_matrices_prange(a, b):
    assert a.ndim == 2
    assert b.ndim == 2
    assert a.shape[0] == b.shape[0]
    K, T = a.shape
    N = b.shape[1]
    result_matrix = np.empty((K, T, N))
    for k in nb.prange(K):
        for t in range(T):
            for n in range(N):
                result_matrix[k, t, n] = a[k, t] + b[k, n]
    return result_matrix
```

Timings:

```py
def yellin(a, b):
    return a[:,:,None] + b[:,None,:]

yellin_njit = nb.njit(yellin) # requires numba.__version__ >= 0.58

@nb.njit
def yellin_reshape_njit(a, b): # compatible with numba.__version__ < 0.58
    K, T = a.shape
    _, N = b.shape
    return a.reshape(K, T, 1) + b.reshape(K, 1, N)

K, T, N = 10, 11, 12
# K, T, N = 300, 400, 500

rng = np.random.default_rng()
a = rng.random((K,T))
b = rng.random((K,N))

result = add_matrices(a, b)

assert np.allclose(result, yellin(a, b))
assert np.allclose(result, yellin_njit(a, b))
assert np.allclose(result, yellin_reshape_njit(a, b))
assert np.allclose(result, add_matrices_prange(a, b))

%timeit -n 1000 add_matrices(a, b)
%timeit -n 1000 yellin(a, b)
%timeit -n 1000 yellin_njit(a, b)
%timeit -n 1000 yellin_reshape_njit(a, b)
%timeit -n 1000 add_matrices_prange(a, b)
```

Results:

`K, T, N = 10, 11, 12`

```
751 ns ± 3.75 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
2.17 µs ± 93 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
1.27 µs ± 31.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
1.91 µs ± 39.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
11.6 µs ± 387 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each) # slow for small K, T, N
```

`K, T, N = 300, 400, 500` `%timeit -n 10`

```
45.8 ms ± 1.75 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
57.6 ms ± 2.57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
60.9 ms ± 2.55 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each) # njit made this slower than pure numpy
85.2 ms ± 2.05 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each) # also slower than pure numpy
19.9 ms ± 311 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each) # fastest for large arrays
```